# Play Video on mouseover or on scroll

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, scrollto

Hi we are using a bit of javascript on this site for a video and have resolved the cookie side of things but we are also looking for a fix so we can also have it so it starts playing once we scroll to the position or when we place the mouse over it needs to stop when we scroll past the video. The js we are using is the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">// <![CDATA[
function played(){
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf("played=") == 0) return 1;
    }
    var date = new Date();
    var days = 7;
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = "played=1"+"; expires="+date.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
    return 0;
}

if(played()==0){
    document.write("<iframe  src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/23237102? title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1\"  frameborder=\"0\" width=\"100%\" height=\"436\" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>");
}
else{
    document.write("<iframe  src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/23237102?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0\" frameborder=\"0\" width=\"100%\" height=\"436\"    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>");
 }
 </script>
```

any suggestions on how this can be done.
Thank you

Comment: *so it starts playing once we scroll to the position or when we place the mouse over it* - This is an aside but it is extremely annoying when web sites do that.

Comment: Because you are using iframes and vimeo, you will need to use `froogaloop`, a Vimeo API. Use it to play and pause videos. Also, what @BSMP said.

Comment: i was looking in to froogaloop but surly there is a way to do this via js